Can I detect that an object is moving in the vertical direction using the mpu6050 sensor?
I have mpu6050 sensor and esp32.I will hang my mpu6050 sensor in a well, I want to find out whether it is hung in the well or not from the mpu6050 sensor.
How can I do this or can it be done with this sensor?
The sensor will be inside a casing and I want to detect it when it touches the ground, how do I do this?
I'm trying to do this by taking acceleration data.
Since the sensor will be perpendicular to the y axis, I expect an acceleration of 9.8 m2/s or more. I do not expect any acceleration in the X and Z axis, but I can ignore small accelerations since it will oscillate while hanging into the well.
I have no idea how to detect it when it touches the ground. Maybe I can determine a threshold value from the fluctuations in the acceleration value, but I am not sure if the same threshold value will be read every time it lands on the ground.
